# PHP Script stops running after qrcode generation

Tags: php, qr-code

Hello so basically I have this working code that generates a qr code image.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
    include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
    require '../db/dbc.php';
    try {
        $characters           = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        $strlength            = 5;
        $string               = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $strlength; $i++) {
            $string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }

        $query       = "INSERT INTO tbl_residents (fname, mname, lname, address, uname, pword, acct_status, department, contact_no, date_reg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt        = $dbc->prepare($query);
        $pword       = sha1($string);
        $now         = date('m/d/Y');
        $acct_status = "active";
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['txt_fn']);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['txt_mn']);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['txt_ln']);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['txt_address']);
        $stmt->bindParam(5, $_POST['txt_un']);
        $stmt->bindParam(6, $pword);
        $stmt->bindParam(7, $acct_status);
        $stmt->bindParam(8, $_POST['txt_dept']);
        $stmt->bindParam(9, $_POST['txt_cnum']);
        $stmt->bindParam(10, $now);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$uncode = intval($string, 36);
// outputs image directly into browser, as PNG stream 
QRcode::png("login-link.php?code=$uncode");


?>
```

If I wanted to add details such as name, department and contact number under the php closing tag, it won't show up. But the code still runs and still generates a qr code image.

Below the php end tag I added this but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ID Creation</title>
</head>
<body>
   Name: <?= $_POST['txt_fn']. " " . $_POST['txt_mn'] . " " . $_POST['txt_fn']; ?>  <br />
   Department: <?= $_POST['txt_dept']; ?>  <br />
   Contact No.: <?= $_POST['txt_cnum']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

If you remove the qr code generation line below, it works.

```
$uncode = intval($string, 36);
// outputs image directly into browser, as PNG stream 
QRcode::png("login-link.php?code=$uncode");
```

So basically, the line QRcode::png("login-link.php?code=$uncode"); stops the code from executing. It doesn't read any lines below it. Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: You can't return HTML from a URL that's supposed to return an image. The URL will be used as the `src` attribute of an image, it won't know what to do with the HTML after it.

Comment: So, is there a solution for this? I am like creating an ID

Comment: You need two scripts, one for the HTML, the other for the image. The first script will put the URL to the second script in the `<img src="...">` tag.

Comment: Can you start the code for me? Just a bit if it's okay for you while I'm doing mine also, thank you

Comment: @Barmar hello I've managed to fix it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello so I've managed to fix my own problem by adding parameter to the qrcode generator and it looks like this

From

```
QRcode::png("login-link.php?code=$uncode");
```

To

```
QRcode::png("login-link.php?code=$uncode", "qr_images/$string.png");
```

And in my html code it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ID Creation</title>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="qr_images/<?= $string.".png"; ?>">
   Name: <?= $_POST['txt_fn']. " " . $_POST['txt_mn'] . " " . $_POST['txt_fn']; ?>  <br />
   Department: <?= $_POST['txt_dept']; ?>  <br />
   Contact No.: <?= $_POST['txt_cnum']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your time looking at my problem.